# How to correctly send post request

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-httpclient

I'm setting up a web app in Angular with a restAPI in Nodejs but I can't correctly set my post request for authenticate user

I've set up my api and I can correctly test it with curl but in the client side (angular) it can't pass the condition that verify that the field required are presents

function in the API:

```js
exports.authenticate = function(req, res) {
  var new_user = new User(req.body);
  if (!new_user.login || !new_user.pwd) {
    res.status(400).send({
      error: true,
      message: 'Please provide all informations!'
    });
  } else {
    User.authenticate(new_user, function(err, user) {
      console.log('controller');
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
      } else {
        console.log(user[0].id);
        var token = jwt.sign({
          id: user[0].id
        }, config.secret, {
          expiresIn: 3600
        });
        res.status(200).send({
          user: user,
          auth: true,
          token: token
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

User.authenticate call my sql query:

```js
sql.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE login = ?", [user.login], function(err, res) {
  if (err) {
    return res.status(500).send('Error  on the server ', err);
    //console.log("error select: ", err);
  } else {
    if (!res) {
      return res.status(404).send('No user found');
    } else {

      //sql.query("UPDATE user SET pwd = ? WHERE id = ?", [crypto.createHash('sha256').update(user.
      sql.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE pwd = ?", [crypto.createHash('sha256').update(user.pwd + r
        if (err) {
          console.log("error: ", err);
          result(null, err);
        } else {


          result(null, res2);
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Angular side (my service function):

```js
login(loguser: User) {
       return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/authenticate`,
               { loguser }, { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')})

                       .pipe(map(user => {
                               // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between p
                               localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                               this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
                               return user;
               }));
       }
```

login component:

```js
onSubmit() {
  this.submitted = true;
  // stop here if form is invalid
  if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
    return;
  }

  this.loading = true;
  this.user.login = this.f.username.value;
  this.user.pwd = this.f.password.value;
  console.log(this.user);
  this.authenticationService.login(this.user)
    .pipe(first())
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
      },
      error => {
        this.error = error;
        this.loading = false;
     });
   }
```

`console.log(this.user)` output : `{login: "cl", pwd: "cl"}`

my post request is blocked in this part of my api:

```
if (!new_user.login || !new_user.pwd){
  res.status(400).send({ error: true, message: 'Please provide all informations!' });
```

Because this is the answer I get when I submit the form.

I can get right answer when I test it like that:

```
curl -v -X POST --data '{"login":"cl","pwd":"cl"}' --header "Content-Type: application/json" https://@api:8443/autenticate
```

I want to get the good answer.

Comment: You're  passing an object with a property named `loguser` which has a value that is `{ login: "cl", pwd: "cl" }`, due to `{ loguser }`. Just pass `loguser` without the brackets.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is in your Angular code:

```
login(loguser: User) {
  return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/authenticate`, 
    { loguser }, 
    {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    })
    .pipe(map(user => {
      // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between p
      localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
      this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
      return user;
    }));
}
```

This piece of code:

```
{ loguser }
```

uses the "shortcut property name" syntax introduced in TypeScript and ECMAScript 2015 to create an object with a single property named `loguser` which has the value of the `loguser` variable. It is equivalent of writing:

```
{ loguser: loguser }
```

Instead, you can just pass the variable itself in your code:

```
login(loguser: User) {
  return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/authenticate`, 
    loguser, // Just the object itself
    {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    })
    .pipe(map(user => {
      // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between p
      localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
      this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
      return user;
    }));
}
```

That will pass the object, with the `login` and `pwd` properties intact.

Comment: thanks you HM . I really appreciate. You've solved my problem (y)